# can't find elements when Headless TRUE in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, navigation, puppeteer, headless, lighthouse

I am trying to navigate to url and login, when use headless:false every thing is going well but I have this error with headless:true **Error! Error: No element found for selector: #email**

````
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--enable-automation'],
    args: [
      `--no-sandbox`,
      `--disable-setuid-sandbox`
    ],
  });

  console.log('Navigating to web page...');
  const page = (await browser.pages())[0];

  await page.goto(url.URL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
  if (url.username && url.password) {
    console.log('Starting login, entering username and password...');
    const submit = await page.$('button[type="submit"]');

    await page.type('#email', url.username);
    await page.type('#password', url.password);

    console.log('Logging in....');
    await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }),
      submit.click(),
    ]);
  }
  return browser;
}```
````

Comment: There's no site provided and none of your code corresponds to the `#email` selector, so I don't see a way to help here.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.